# How to draw an 100 sided regular polygon

Tags: java, loops, polygon

I am trying to draw a regular circle and an 100 sided regular polygon. I can draw the regular circle:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Shapes extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JButton button;
    private JPanel panel;
    public static void main(String[] args){

    }    

    private void createLine(){

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT-ON-CLOSE);
        Container window=getContentPane();
        window.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        panel=new JPanel();
        panel.SetPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 700));
        panel.setBackground(Color.white);
        window.add(panel);

        button=new JButton("OK");
        window.add(button);
        button.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

        Graphics paper= panel.getGraphics();
        int r = 75;
        int x = 300;
        int y = 150;

        paper.drawOval(x,y,r,r);
    }
}
```

I don't know how to draw the regular 100 sided polygon (do you use a loop function?)

Can somebody please help me?

Comment: You'd have to use geometry math to figure out all 100 vertexes of such polygon and draw it line by line. You can try `for` loop (which is not a function), but loop used is not important here.

Comment: I realise I can use the for loop, but I don't how to apply it

Answer (score 3):

This is a general solution to creating a regular polygon with n vertices (n - 1 sides). The `Rectangle` parameter is for setting the bounds

Basically, the idea is starting at the center of the Rectangle, you rotate around the area to the n vertices (360/n as the rotation step). Source is also available [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/ui/shape/PolygonFactory.java)

```
public static Polygon createPolygon(int vertices, double angleOffset, Rectangle r) {
        if (vertices < 1) throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Vertices must be > 0");
        double step = 2 * Math.PI / vertices;
        int[] x = new int[vertices];
        int[] y = new int[vertices];
        int xrad = r.width / 2;
        int yrad = r.height / 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < vertices; i++) {
            x[i] = r.x + xrad + (int) (Math.cos(angleOffset + i * step) * xrad);
            y[i] = r.y + yrad + (int) (Math.sin(angleOffset + i * step) * yrad);
        }
        Polygon p = new Polygon(x, y, vertices);
        return p;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to figure out the angle for each corner, which would be the same for each in a regular polygon.  Then how long you want each side to be.  Then run a for loop to add all points to the polygon object.

[Take a look at this example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/DrawaPolygon.htm).